# Logistic Equation regarding population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I had this question on an exam where it asked when will the population reach 70% of the carrying capacity, given that the initial population is twice that of the carrying capacity is modelled as:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = 0.4P(1-\frac{0.00001}{0.4}P)$$.

The answer was 'never' but is this a conceptual thing? Since if it's over the carrying capacity, the minimum it can go to is the capacity? Also, can someone confirm that the carrying capacity (L) is 40 for this question from 0.4/0.01? And by substituting the initial population $P_{0} = $80, L=40, p(t)=56 k=0.4 into the equation below, you get $t=\frac{ln(56)}{-32}$ which is a negative hence it's not possible? Thanks!

$$
P=\frac{L}{1+A e^{-k t}}, \quad A=\frac{L-P_{0}}{P_{0}}
$$